# Accessing external server through Azure VPN with NAT

Tags: vpn, snat, azure

I have three sites and an external server (10.13.16.5) that are connecting to Azure via IPsec tunnels. I do not control the network at the external service but they have given me an address block of 10.13.17.0/24.

[image: Network Layout]

If I spin up a VM on the 10.13.17.0 subnet I can access the server, so the tunnel works.
I have tried created an egress NAT policy in Azure with the following settings but was unsuccessful in accessing the server.

| Type | Mode | Internal | External |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dynamic | EgressSnat | 10.1.1.0/24 | 10.13.17.0/26 |

All tunnels are up and able to pass traffic between each other, but nothing is able to get to the external server.

Not sure what needs to happen NAT wise to get this to function through Azure.

Comment: You have all private addresses, so you do not want to NAT. You only NAT when you must: public<->private or overlapping addressing. Simply route.